# Absolute path issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I have an ActionResult in some controller and i want to return a view from another controller
I am doing this:

```
return View(VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute(@"~/Views/Order/Index.aspx"));
```

I see that page (there is a jqgrid on it) but not fully loaded, jqgrid makes an ajax request to get the data but the request fails, thing which doesn't happen if the absolute path is correct.
So, is that the correct way to get the absolute url of a view? because i don't understand why the ajax call fails.

Comment: Can you identify the difference between the resulting URLs of both the working and non-working ajax calls?  You can use a proxy or Firebug to step through it and identify the differences.

Comment: it's working when the page is in the same controller and i am using return View()...when the view is in some other controller i am using firebug and there is a problem with the ajax call for the source method of the grid

Answer (score 0):

I think You don't need the abs stuff. Does this work?

```
return View(@"~/Views/Order/Index.aspx");
```

Comment: nope..same problem...the source method for the jqgrid doesn't fire